# Combine/Merge 2 arrays while re-indexing in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I think there is a function for what I want, but I cannot find it in the PHP docs. Let's imagine I have the following arrays:

```
$first = array(
    0 => 'howdy',
    1 => 'hello',
    2 => 'wassup'
);

$second = array(
    0 => 'aloha',
    1 => 'yo',
    2 => 'hi'
);
```

In the end, I want to combine them to be something like:

```
array(
    0 => 'howdy',
    1 => 'hello',
    2 => 'wassup',
    3 => 'aloha',
    4 => 'yo',
    5 => 'hi'   
)
```

The two important criteria are:

1) No values with equivalent keys or values are overwritten

2) The array is re-indexed, maintaining the order of the keys within the individual arrays and the first array's values have lower key values that the second array.

I know how I could do this writing a function, but I swear that there is a PHP function that does that and I want to use it if someone can identify it for me.

Comment: You'll face-palm when you realise how obvious the solution is

Comment: @Phil - I swear to you, I read the array_merge doc 3 times today. WOW! Off. My. Game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge):

```
array_merge($first, $second);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => howdy
    [1] => hello
    [2] => wassup
    [3] => aloha
    [4] => yo
    [5] => hi
)
```

Comment: Thank you...it works. Example #3 in the doc made it seem as though the values with the same key would be overwritten.

Comment: To clarify, read this statement from the same page: If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Comment: TimCooper - I'm having a bad day ;) I meant to say Example #2. @danontheline - thank you...that explanation makes a lot of sense.